# How to make widgets in a row the same width as the widest from them

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For example, we have next widget:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        OutlinedButton(
          child: Text('B 1'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        OutlinedButton(
          child: Text('BB 2'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        OutlinedButton(
          child: Text('BBBBB 5'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can we create all buttons (`'B1'` and `'BB 2'`) to have the same width as the widest last one (`'BBBBB 5'`). So resulting `MyWidget` width will be the width of `'BBBBB 5'` button multiply 3.

And yes, text on buttons can vary; that is why we can't precalculate and hardcode their width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to combo `IntrinsicWidth` with any `Flex` widget, such as `Expanded` here.

If you wrap all of your children with an `Expanded`, you'll end up sharing evenly the space between them all, the thing is that you actually *don't want that* because eventually you will have a `Row` filling all the available space with 3 buttons with a lot of "white" space.

Because you want the buttons to all have the exactly same width as the bigger sibling, you first will have to wrap each child with an `Expanded` widget and then wrap the `Row` with an `IntrinsicWidth` widget, which will force all the children to share the width of the bigger one.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              child: Text('B 1'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              child: Text('BB 2'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              child: Text('BBBBB 5'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]